# RESTEasy client requests initially have "Accept-Encoding: gzip" while documentation says otherwise

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I'm invoking a HTTP GET request to another system using RESTEasy with `resteasy-client:3.12.1.Final` (provided by WildFly 20.0.1.Final).

```java
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build;
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(fromPath(url));
Response response = target.request()
  .header(AUTHORIZATION, "Basic <authentication_token>")
  .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
  .get()
```

As you can see, I don't configure anything "special" in the `ResteasyClientBuilder` but for some reason all requests contain this header parameter: `Accept-Encoding: gzip` which causes some trouble on the remote side.

The [RESTEasy documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.12.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e1984) however states:

> RESTEasy supports (though not by default - see below) GZIP
> decompression. If properly configured, the client framework or a
> JAX-RS service, upon receiving a message body with a Content-Encoding
> of "gzip", will automatically decompress it. The client framework can
> (though not by default - see below) automatically set the
> Accept-Encoding header to be "gzip, deflate" so you do not have to set
> this header yourself.

From my understanding the `gzip` parameter should not be set by default. Or are there any other possible default configurations which might add this parameter?

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: The WildFly version is `20.0.1.Final`.

Comment: If I use a browser I see that. If however I use a client I do not see the gzip entry.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I digged a little deeper and found out the following. If I use a new `ResteasyClient` and `ResteasyWebTarget` in a JUnit test, then the `Accept-Encoding` header is not present. If I debug the client reqest during runtime, then the header is present. As far as I can tell, the major difference is that the code is running deployed in the Wildfly server. So maybe there is some configuration in the Wildfly server I'm not aware of?

Comment: Just to confirm you're executing the client in the container from something like a servlet or another endpoint?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The flow goes something like this: The WAR deployment provides a POST endpoint which is scanned via the `resteasy-servlet-initializer`. This endpoint method invokes a service call which then creates the client and issues another request to a third-party system.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure. I've not had a chance to try to crate a reproducer. Not that it likely matters, but have you tried using the JAX-RS client instead RESTEasy Client?

Answer (score 0):

**You might want to try this:**

```
Variant variant = new Variant(MediaType.JSON_APPLICATION, "", "gzip");
Response response = client.target(generateURL("/big/send")).request().post(Entity.entity(b, variant));
```